# Android - move drawable with animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm new to Android and need advice. I have a GridLayout with multiple ImageViews. Each ImageView has a drawable and a background color. On button click, I want to **animate** two things, depending on user's input: 1) move the entire view to a new position (this part is clear and doesn't cause problems), and 2) move **only the image's drawable** to a new cell, leaving the view with the background color at the original position. I'm completely stuck on this second task. How do I move drawables using animation? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you researched this? What have you found and what have you tried? Please paste the code you have troubles with.

Comment: This looks like some kind of a game. Is that true? If so, maybe you should consider using other drawing methods than a GridLayout?

Comment: @Anton Yes, I have read on Property Animation, TranslateAnimation, ObjectAnimator. All animation I tried leave the empty cell in the GridLayout when the View moves, while I need the View background color stay at its original position, so that there wouldn't be an empty cell.

Comment: @Zielony It's a kind of an interactive construction set, of sort. The thing is that the GridLayout is just fine for my project, the only trouble I have is this animation part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> move only the image's drawable to a new cell, leaving the view with the background color at the original position

I think you can't "move a drawable". But you can do the following:

- introduce a `View` - let's call it *movingDrawableView* - showing just the drawable but with a transparent background, this `View` is hidden at first
- Set the position of this *movingDrawableView* to overlap the `View` with the drawable and the colored background and make it visible
- Set the drawable of the `View` with the colored background to `null`
- start the animation for *movingDrawableView*
- as soon as the animation is finished, fill the underlying `View` with the drawable and show a background as required
- hide *movingDrawableView*

Comment: But how can I overlap the View in the GridLayout? When I try to set a new View to the position of another View, it just adds a new cell into the GridLayout and rearranges the indexes without overlapping.

Comment: @D.S. - if you let the GridLayout be a child of some other ViewGroup (e.g. a FrameLayout), then you can have a View which is not a child of the GridLayout but of the parent ViewGroup. This "free" View can move "across" the GridLayout (like a pawn in a game) .

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.